# My task is blocked with the function Task.WhenAll(allTasks) after doing some tasks

Tags: c#

Is there an option to stop tasks if they exceed a certain time?

Comment: If you really have an _inifinite_ loop, it must be inside `ProcessFile`. Both of these loops are _finite_ (however they can be really long, so they will _appear infinite_ ).

Comment: no that piece of code isn't the problem _by itself_, if the process file function never returns then you will never meet the when all condition likewise file processing is a locking action so if the files are on the harddrive the move files you process simultaneously the slower they run as they are all taking turns requesting and waiting for the harddisk to be free

Comment: Is `ProcessFile` IO bound or CPU bound? you typically use async for the former, and parallelism for the later.

Comment: a better option would be to have a queue that you push the files into then loop through all the files in turn

Comment: @MikeT TPL DataFlow comes to mind ...

Comment: More code is needed to provide a more exact answer.

Comment: If there is File I/O involved here (which it seems to be) then mind that _all of these tasks_ battle for the same resource _at once_. That code may actually suffer from managing collisions more than the actual processing is taking time. Including possible dead-locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to process the files asynchronously then i would suggest using a channel as a file queue something like

```
var fileQueue = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

async Task write(List<string> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        await fileQueue.Writer.WriteAsync(item);
    }
    fileQueue.Writer.TryComplete()
}
async Task read()
{
    while(await fileQueue.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        var filename = await fileQueue.Reader.ReadAsync();
        await ProcessFile(filename);
    }

}

var writer = write(list);
var reader = read();

await Task.WaitAll(writer, reader);
```

EDIT: you have edited your question with a second question

you can abort a running task but this is generally a bad idea as you have no guarantee that the code it in a fit state to stop what it is doing

the preferred approach is to pass in a `cancellation token` then the running task periodically checks the token and if it indicates that a cancel is requested it gracefully cancels